# Retrieve the normal vector of a plane in affine coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry, affine-geometry

Given an affine coordinate system $[O; e_{1,2,3}]$ and its associated Gram matrix $G$ (i.e. $G=(e_i,e_j)_{ij}$ where the parenthese denote inner product), is there any slick way to retrieve the normal vector of the plane 
$$A_1x_1+A_2x_2+A_3x_3=0.$$

If we can find two independent vectors that span the plane, we're basically done. But there are infinitely many of them and they aren't that straightforward to compute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Calculate $n=G^{-1}A$, where $A$ is the vector with coordinates $A_i$. Then note that the dot product of $n$ and $x$ is given by 
$$n^\top Gx = (G^{-1}A)^\top Gx = A^\top G^{-1}Gx = A^\top x = 0.$$

Comment: Thanks this is very nice. May I ask how did you obtain the choice of $n$? Is there deeper reasons behind?

Comment: I see it might have been to work from $(\cdot)Gx$ where $\cdot$ is what we want and associate it with $A^Tx=0$. No worries.

Comment: I obtained it by running the displayed (thanks for that!) equation from right to left. This is how you work in non-orthonormal coordinate systems with the matrix $G$. It is called the first fundamental form in differential geometry.